# partial numerical array - pattern matching

Tags: time-series, numerical, fuzzy-classification

I have a linear numerical array `source` and I want to find/match `test` array as pattern :

```
source = [39,36,23,21,28,36,30,22,34,37]
test = [36,23,21,28]
```

we can use `brute force` or similar method for finding the **exact match**, by checking `test` array from index `0` to `len(source)-len(test)`

but in our problem, we can accept this pattern too ( order is important )

```
test = [36,24,21,28] // changed 23 to 24
```

since we have many different ways of solving this problem ( maybe fuzzy!),
I want to know the title of some solutions.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what a correct match should be? Does the test have to be a consecutive subsequence with minor modification? Does order matter or a sequence with the same numbers in a different order can also be a match? Are you interested in a similarity score?

Comment: the big problem is I am in the middle of a problem without any background knowledge.The answer for your first and second questions are <yes>. the order is  important too. lets put it in this way , I can accept the array as matched with ±2 units change for each element.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition (consecutive, order matters, max +/-2 difference), it's not a fuzzy matching case. It's just a minor variant of searching a subsequence:

```
for i=0 to len(source)-len(test) {
  j=0
  while (j<len(test)) && (abs(source[i+j]-test[j]) <= 2) {
    j++
  if (j == len(test)) { 
     // match found
  }
}
```

This is the simple version, in case efficiency is an issue there is a more efficient version using dynamic programming.